# AttributeError: 'SelectQuery' object has no attribute 'is_active'

Tags: python, flask, attributeerror, peewee, flask-peewee

I'm trying to learn the Peewee ORM in combination with Flask by following the [Flask Mega Tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world). In [part 5 of the tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins) I create a login using OpenID. After overcoming a bunch of hurdles already I now get an AttributeError in the function pasted below on the following line: `login_user(user, remember = remember_me)`.

```
@oid.after_login
def after_login(resp):
    if resp.email is None or resp.email == "":
        flash('Invalid login. Please try again.')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    user = User.select().where(User.email == resp.email)    
    if user.wrapped_count() == 0:
        nickname = resp.nickname
        if nickname is None or nickname == "":
            nickname = resp.email.split('@')[0]
        user = User(nickname = nickname, email = resp.email, role = models.ROLE_USER)
        user.save()
    remember_me = False
    if 'remember_me' in session:
        remember_me = session['remember_me']
        session.pop('remember_me', None)
    login_user(user, remember = remember_me)
    return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('index'))
```

`is_active` is found in my User model as follows:

```
class User(db.Model):
    nickname = TextField()
    email = TextField()
    role = IntegerField(default = ROLE_USER)

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.nickname)
```

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong here though. Could anybody give me a helping hand in what I'm doing wrong here?

All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the error suggests, `user = User.select().where(User.email == resp.email)` gives you back a `SelectQuery`, not an instance of `User`. You'll want to include an additional method call to actually fetch the record, something like `.first()`. `first` will return either an instance of `User` or `None`.

This would allow you to slightly adjust your code:

```
user = User.select().where(User.email == resp.email).first()
if not user:  # or if user is None:
    nickname = resp.nickname
    ...
```

Comment: I'm new to peewee, but I think currently the equivalent of `first()` is `get()`